# Can xts deal with several time series with identical time indices?

Tags: r, time-series, xts

Let's consider a simultaneous data collection:

```
library(xts)
d <- data.frame(t = Sys.time()-1:10, a = 1:10, b = 11:20 )
```

I can create a time serie object using:

```
df.xts <- xts(d$a, order.by=d$t)
```

What if I want to have the time serie to describe the two variables a and b, like

```
df.xts <- xts(c(d$a,d$b), order.by=c(d$t,d$t))
```

The result seem to merge both data:

```
                [,1]
2018-02-16 15:13:19   10
2018-02-16 15:13:19   20
2018-02-16 15:13:20    9
2018-02-16 15:13:20   19
2018-02-16 15:13:21    8
```

Is there a way to split the two variables in the same time serie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is a way:

```
df.xts <- xts(cbind(d$a, d$b), order.by = d$t)
```

The first argument is

> an object containing the time series data

meaning that it may be multivariate, as in your case, while the second argument is

> a corresponding vector of unique times/dates

so there is no need to provide a matrix of times/dates.